# Converting gatsby project from css to scss, having issues with lost grid preprocessing

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, postcss, gatsby

I'm taking a gatsby starter project that uses [Lost grid](https://github.com/peterramsing/lost) and converting from css to scss for some gains.  This is the starter project:  https://github.com/wpioneer/gatsby-starter-lumen

Essentially, I'm converting the project to scss because I much prefer it's structure and would like to move away from all the css files.  For now, I simply:

- Installed `sass-loader`, `scss`, and `node-sass`
- Renamed all the css files to scss files
- And modified `gatsby-node.js` to the following:

  ```
  var rucksack = require('rucksack-css')
  var lost = require("lost")
  var cssnext = require("postcss-cssnext")

  exports.modifyWebpackConfig = function(config, env) {
      config.merge({
          postcss: [
              lost(),
              rucksack(),
              cssnext({
                  browsers: ['>1%', 'last 2 versions']
              })
          ]
      })

      config.loader('svg', {
         test: /\.(svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
         loader: 'file-loader',
      })

      config.loader('sass', {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
      })

      return config
  };
  ```

Unfortunately, while this does allow me to build and run the project using scss, I've noticed that my sweet Lost grid has disappeared.  After investigation, I notice that `.sidebar` is still reading as `lost-column: 1/3` in the browser (for example), so I can see that the preprocessing which is crucial for Lost grid didn't happen.

Honestly, this is probably an issue outside of Lost grid, and rather an issue with how I've constructed the `gatsby-node.js`, but I would appreciate any insight into what I'm missing.  I don't mind uploading a **scss/lost starter project for gatsby** once this issue is resolved.

Comment: That will require postcss-loader & postcss-lost to get that working.

Comment: Why are you adding the sass-loader config? Gatsby already includes that by default? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/45c1fd346349e98a88728710880cd2a3813e787e/lib/utils/webpack.config.js#L310

Comment: @KyleMathews, guess that was a mistake.  However, I don't think that should cause the lost-grid to not preprocess...

Comment: @RyanZim, I have `postcss-loader` and `lost` in my `package.json`, but I don't know what `postcss-lost` is, doesn't seem to be an npm package...

Comment: Oops, the npm package is named lost, not postcss-lost. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lost Not a webpack expert, so I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: Cool, was just wondering. Wouldn't expect it to affect things either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In `node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/webpack.config.js`, I changed

```
    // CSS modules
    config.loader('cssModules', {
      test: /\.module\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'postcss']
    });
    config.loader('lessModules', {
      test: /\.module\.less/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'less']
    });
    config.loader('sassModules', {
      test: /\.module\.(sass|scss)/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'sass']
    });
```

to:

```
    // CSS modules
    config.loader('lessModules', {
      test: /\.module\.less/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'less']
    });
    config.loader('sassModules', {
      test: /\.module\.(sass|scss)/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'sass']
    });
    config.loader('cssModules', {
      test: /\.module\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style', cssModulesConfDev, 'postcss']
    });
```

I'll probably see what the gatsby folks see about making this change permanent.